# I want to read a xml file and store only specific tags into a new xml file using java?

Tags: xml, readxml, writexml

Ex: Xmlfile.xml( id, name, age, email)  and newxmlfile.xml(email).

Comment: Sounds like a job for XSLT (which can be easily run from Java using the JAXP Transformer).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.